# Show all rows in MySQL that contain the same value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database:

```
ID | Name
1  | Bob
2  | James
3  | Jack
4  | Bob
5  | James
```

How would I return a list of all the columns where the same name appears more than once, eg, I'd like to return this:

```
1  | Bob
2  | James
4  | Bob
5  | James
```

I've written a count query:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) 
AS NumOccurrences 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING ( COUNT(Name) > 1 )
```

But that just returns something like this:

```
Bob   | 2
James | 2
```

Whereas I want to return the full rows returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this sql query:

```
select distinct a.name, a.id 
from table a, table b 
where a.name = b.name and a.id != b.id
```

Comment: I think this should be the selected answer

Comment: How do you apply this when you're looking in the same table?

Comment: You are the best.

Answer (score 24):

You can do it with a sub select

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT Name FROM table GROUP BY Name HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Also if your distinction match is multiple columns, you can use cartesian sets:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (firstName, lastName) IN (
    SELECT firstName, lastName FROM table GROUP BY firstName, lastName HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: this is just too slow for a big tables and a lot of columns, sorry

Answer (score 5):

**Try this**

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS NumOccurrences 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```